# ES6 isomorphic-fetch does not send headers

Tags: reactjs, cors, es6-promise

I'm developing my first front-end app based on React. The aim of this app is to connect to a RESTful API in order to get and post data. The problem is I can't send the token header to pass the security check so the request fails.

I get different errors depend on the browser I use.

This is my main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import promise from 'es6-promise';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

promise.polyfill();

class Employee extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {employees : []};
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/app/rest/employees',{ method: 'get', headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080', 'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded', 'token' : '93edf459ba78d13be0e9d21143238f43796de1f6ebbc58b133af7f33b8222676'}})
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((downscalings) => {
        this.setState({ employees: values });
      })
  }

  update(){
    this.setState({name : 'John'});
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
        <input type="text" value="aaaa"></input>
        <button onClick={this.update}>Set name</button>
      </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Employee/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This is the output log error from the browser:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (No Autorizado)
index.html:1 Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/app/rest/employees. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch(…)
```

This is the net trace:

GET employees

localhost:8080

0 B

OPTIONS employees

401 Not authorized

localhost:8080

37 B

[image]

I assume that the headers are not sent so the REST service refuses the request. I also added the CORS header because of the warning. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how the backend wants the token

Comment: Can you please display the Request headers and Response headers from the network calls recorded by your browser?

Comment: @Aatif Bandey The backend gets the token from the header "token". I thin that it is implied in the code I show.

Comment: what you see in network tab i mean the method is it `OPTIONS` or `POST`

Comment: @JeremyColin the get request does not allow me to see anything. In Firebug I see the GET employees like loading and the OPTIONS employees allows me to see headers but it does not have mine.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is response header sent after your _OPTIONS_ request.

You should configure your backend server CORS to allow requests from your frontend. What backend do you use?

Comment: @cema-sp but why I can´t see the headers I'm trying to send? My backend is developed using Spring. I can access it using Postman and everything is at localhost.

Comment: @AatifBandey I've just added a picture

Comment: it means you are not posting in right way

Comment: try it with postman and check

Comment: @mannuk Postman may not use as strong security settings as browser do. Does your frontend served on the same port as backend? Try running backend on `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to response my own answer. Thanks to @cema-sp for the key to find what was happening.

The problem here was related to the CORS configuration in my Spring project. This Spring project exposes a REST API based on token security. It had two problems:

1-The OPTIONS request was blocked by the security token filter:

I wasn't aware how CORS works. CORS, Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, defines a mechanism to enable client-side cross-origin requests.  CORS are widely supported by modern browsers like FireFox, Chrome, Safari, and IE. If you just run my fetch and call the backend, you may notice that the GET request is changed to OPTIONS and there is a GET request waiting (You can see that looking to the image at my initial post). The browser sends an OPTIONS request to the server, and the server needs to send the response with correct headers. So that, you need to add these headers to the OPTIONS request.

In the response you have to include which headers are available to the front-end app. In my case, I added the token header to authenticate the requests. If you are using spring 3.1 you need to create a filter like this:

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                                    throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            // CORS "pre-flight" request
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, token");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");// 30 min
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

and then add it to the web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>es.predictia.dp.web.security.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

if you are using spring 4 check this post https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

2-It was resetting all the responses in order to avoid the jsessionid be injected in the response. Now I remove the set-cookie directly.

Thanks everyone